# Macro to paste a hyperlink in MS Word

Tags: ms-word

I would like to paste a link in Word, but my code only pastes plain text.

```
Sub test()
ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:="https://docs.google.com/xxxxxx"
End Sub
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
With ActiveDocument
  .Hyperlinks.Add .Characters.Last, "https://docs.google.com/xxxxxx", , , "Google Docs"
End With
End Sub
```